# How to create GWT CellTable with Parent-Child rows

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

I have a date template:

```
Parent captions: Caption1, Caption2..., CaptionN
    Child captions: Caption1, Caption2..., CaptionN

Parent Row1: Cell1, Cell2..., CellN
    Child Row1: Cell1, Cell2..., CellN
    Child Row2: Cell1, Cell2..., CellN
    ...
    Child RowN: Cell1, Cell2..., CellN
...
Parent RowN....
```

Parent can have 0, 1 or multiple children.

Is it possible to render hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite straightforward using cell tables or data grids. You need to add a custom table builder. The original feature/enhancement/issue can be found on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit-contributors/kt7bOPvkdMQ) with a showcase here [CustomDataGrid](http://showcase2.jlabanca-testing.appspot.com/#!CwCustomDataGrid).

Comment: Thank, Pauli, for hint to CellTableBuilder API. It was unknown API for me.